# Packaging multiple MSi files into a single msi

Tags: wix, windows-installer

Am new to Wix, i have a situation where in i have 2 different addins that has been developed using the adx com addin, and now there is a need for release where in a single msi file should install these 2 addins (i have created 2 different addins).

1. Could you please suggest if i can install these 2 addins in a single wix installer. keeping in mind that these 2 addins will have a seperate registry entry in the registry.
2. or, i can bundle these to msi inside a single msi file using the bootstrapper.
   2.1. i used the chaining functionality with MSIPackage element and the project built successfully, but on installing this msi, there was an error " This installation package could not be opened. Contact the application vendor.......", further analyzing the issue, i understood its because there is no entry point defined for a msi file. i was able to achieve this as an exe, but the client prefers an msi rather.

Any help appreciated.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: WIX Bootstrapper (BURN) generates an exe which wraps your MSI's into a single executable. To create a seamless setup experience across multiple installation packages, the WiX toolset provides an engine (often referred to as a bootstrapper or chainer) named Burn.

Comment: The Burn engine is an executable that hosts a DLL called the "bootstrapper application". The bootstrapper application DLL is responsible for displaying UI to the end-user and directs the Burn engine when to carry out download, install, repair and uninstall actions. YOu cannot generate an MSI out of BURN, sure you can rename the executable to .MSI but they wont have similar characteristics :)

Comment: am able to achieve an exe from the Burn, just wanted to make sure there is no option to get a chained package output as .msi.

Comment: can we add 2 addins into a single wix installer ?

Comment: Yes, why do you think you can't do that?

Answer (score 0):

You can add your `adx com addins` as two separate features in one wix project, and then a single msi can install both for you, it doesn't matter that there would be separate files or registry keys.

Why does your customer want an msi? If you do use burn, the executable is still executing separate msi's and so you will still have the benefits of using windows installer, even though the containing file is an exe bootstrapper.

Comment: Thank you, but, how do i do that, could you please suggest on this. the client requires that because they can edit the msi using instEd to add some command line and change a few stuff.

Comment: can we add 2 addins into a single wix installer ?

Comment: What does your addin deliverable look like? A file and a registry key? Many files and registry keys? I don't see why you can't follow my suggestion of placing each addin in it's own feature.